# How to attach a listener like oncomplete to p:button

Tags: facebook, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following code :

```
<h:form id="facebookForm">
    <p:button value="Facebook Connect" href="#{loginPageCode.facebookUrlAuth}">  
          <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{loginPageCode.getUserFromSession}" update="growl confirmDialog" ></p:ajax>
    </p:button>

    <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Welcome"
                        header="Welcome to our website!" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
         <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                            <h:outputText id="msg" value="Salutation : #{user.salutation}" />
                            <h:outputText id="msg1" value="Name and surname: #{user.name} #{user.surname}" />
                            <h:outputText id="msg2" value="Birthday : #{user.birthDate}" />
                            <h:outputText id="msg3" value="Email : #{user.email}" />
                            <h:outputText id="msg4" value="Postal code : #{user.postalCode}" />
                            <h:outputText id="msg5" value="Phone nr : #{user.phoneNumber}" />
         </h:panelGrid>
         <p:commandButton id="confirmation" value="Ok" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />
    </p:confirmDialog>

    <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" showDetail="true" />

</h:form>
```

I am trying to connect to *facebook* from my webpage, through a custom `servlet` which handles all the stuff regarding validation, parsing response, etc. The `href` inside above form contains the url to facebook authentification, which in the end redirects everything to the current page, which is `index.xhtml`.

What I want to do is to call a method after everything was done, something like `onComplete` attribute from `<p:commandButton>` component, because I want to display a dialog with updated managed bean, `<p:confirmDialog>`, and to welcome. So I need to first go to the first **URL**, wait until autenthification is finished, then call this method `#{loginPageCode.getUserFromSession}` which dinamically updates the managed bean under the hood by parsing JSON from facebook http response, and then to open the dialog which contains updated values.

I have tried also to use `<p:commandButton>` with `type="button"` to use `action` / `actionListener` / `update` capabilities, but unsuccessful.
Can you please advise? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you get anything back from the facebook after completed authentication? Like a parameter or something?

Comment: Well, I get a JSON object, which I handle in one servlet. But I need to call the #{loginPageCode.getUserFromSession} as to populate the managed bean with informations from facebook.

Comment: Strange requirement. Why don't you do the job in (post)constructor of the bean associated with `index.xhtml` which FB connect is apparently redirecting to in the end?

Comment: @BalusC : I have one User bean which I want to fill either by a simple form (name, surname, etc), either by taking values from facebook response after autenthication. So I want only when the user clicks the facebook button to connect to the facebook.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for tip. I did what you've said and it works now. Can you write an answer so I can accept and close the thread? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking/misgrasping how HTTP and ajax in general work. It's not possible to have an ajax oncomplete hook on a synchronous GET request.

Just do the job in the (post)constructor of the request/view scoped associated with `index.xhtml` which FB authentication is ultimately redirecting to, if necessary based on some specific request parameters which you've specified in `index.xhtml` callback URL.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to do most of your processing in the back. Try this

1. Define a `preRenderView` event in which you'll do most of the postprocessing of the facebook login. This event will be defined in **index.xhtml**. Your code will look something like this

   ```
   <f:metadata>
     <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginPageCode.postFBProcessing}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   In `postFBProcessing`, you'll carry out whatever processing you need to do after return from FB (processing the JSON response, getting user from session etc).
2. Define a boolean `dialogVisible` in your backing bean and bind the `<p:dialog/>`'s `visible` property to the variable OR use `RequestContext` to update the dialog.

   ```
   <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Welcome" visible="#{loginPageCode.isDialogVisible}" header="Welcome to our website!" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
   ```